# Delegate compiles with different return types

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Let's say I have a class that looks like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    public static void DoWork(MyDelegate aDelegate)
    {
         aDelegate();
    }
}
```

And I have some code that looks like:

```
var myBool = false;
MyClass.DoWork(() => myBool = true);
```

The above builds as expected.  What I can't make sense of is if I change the return type on MyDelegate to bool, *it still builds*.  To top it off, if I change the return type to say, int, the lambda will show a compilation error of:

```
Cannot convert expression type 'bool' to return type 'int'.
```

This leaves me with two questions:

**Why are both void and bool acceptable for the delegate's return type?**

**Why is the expression type on my lambda bool?  Is it not void?**

Thanks!

Comment: first of all the assignment expression `myBool = true` assigns `true` to myBool and returns it. that is why it compiles when the return type is bool. but I have no idea why it compiles with `void`.it seems that compiler is smart enough to remove implicit return when you make the return type void and just perform the assignment

Comment: Rather than creating a new delegate, `MyDelegate`, you can just use `Action` or `Func<bool>` respectively for either void returning or `bool` returning parameter-less delegates.

Comment: @Servy thanks for answer, and yes, it would be more appropriate to avoid the delegate declaration in this case and use Func<bool>.  Good tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is both void and bool acceptable for the delegate's return type?

Lambdas are rather unusual in this regard.  They are one of very few expressions in C# that are contextual, that is they do different things depending on the context in which the expression is used.

In this case the compiler looks at what you are trying to assign the lambda to, and uses that in determining what the type of that lambda should be.  It sees that the lambda needs to be of type `MyDelegate`, and attempts to match the lambda to that delegate.  The lambda that you have resolves to an expression of type `bool`, but if the delegate is of type `void` the return type will be ignored, allowing you to have a non-void lambda assigned to a void returning delegate.

> Why is the expression type on my lambda bool? Is it not void?

The assignment operator isn't `void` returning; it resolves to the value that was assigned to the variable, so in this case, it resolves to `true`.

So with a simpler code snippet:

```
bool variable;
bool anotherVariable = (variable = true);
```

(The parenthesis here are not needed, and are only there for clarity as to the order of execution.)

both `variable` and `anotherVariable` will be `true` after running this.  `variable = true` will assign `true` to `variable`, return `true`, and then assign that to `anotherVariable`.